# Checking if an evaluation function over a metric space is a linear functional and is continuous or not

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $\mathcal C^0$ = {$f : (0, 1) → \mathbb R$ | f is continuous}. Equip $\mathcal C^0$ with the $L_2$ norm, for $f \in \mathcal C^0$, $$||f||_2 = \sqrt{\int_0^1(f(x))^2dx}$$

and metric
$$ d(f,g) = ||f-g||_2 $$

to make it a metric space.  For a given $\beta \in (0,1)$, define the evaluation function as $E_{\beta} : \mathcal C^0 → \mathbb R$ and $E_{\beta}(f) = f(\beta)$. I need to prove or disprove the following statements:

1. $E_{\beta}$ is a linear functional on $\mathcal C^0$.
2. $E_{\beta}$ is discontinuous for all $\beta \in (0,1)$

I think 1 is true, since $E_{\beta}(f+g) = f(\beta) + g(\beta)$ and $E_{\beta}(\lambda f) = \lambda f(\beta)$

I have no idea, however, about how to get started on the second part. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is almost the same as the following: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855850/linear-function-that-is-not-continuous?rq=1

Comment: The norm on $\mathcal{C}^0$ seems not well-defined, e.g. the norm of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ doesn't exist because the integral is infinite. After you fix this, ad. (2) think about two functions $f, g \in \mathcal{C}^0$ such that $f(\beta) = g(\beta) + 1$ but the area between the graphs of these functions is really small.

Comment: @Adayah I'm not too sure what you mean by 'such that $f(\beta)=g(\beta)+1$ but the area between the graphs of these functions is really small', could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @Adayah Basically, is it even possible for that condition to be satisfied? I can't think of any functions that satisfy this

Comment: Elaborating would require me to write an answer. But I can't do it until you've fixed the question because the details might be important.

Comment: The norm is just defined as the 2-norm shown above. Could examples for f, g be given with whatever is originally mentioned?